# Compare query from database with string C#

Tags: c#, string, compare

I am making a program in C# with access database. I want to check if a string from the database is in a string.
I have a table named keyword and I have a string who has some text in it. So, I want to check if any of the strings in the database is in the text, one by one.
Let's say I have this in my database:

```
"ABC", "CDE", "EFG"
```

and I have this text:

```
string a = "and abc asd dsa efg"
```

And I want to fill a label - if is true "The string has ABC, EFG" else "NO MATCH"

Thanks in advance,
dnisko

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First populate table column values into a string List.

```
 SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(/*Database connection credentails*/);

 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select columnName from table", con); 
 DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
 da.Fill(ds); 

 List<string> keyValues= new List<string>();
 foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 {
   keyValues.Add(row["columnName"].ToString());
 }
```

Then search for string in text one by one.

```
 string a = "and abc asd dsa efg";
 string matchedKeys=string.Empty;
 bool matchFound = false;


 foreach(string key in keyValues)
 {
    if(a.Contains(key))
    {
       matchFound=true;
       matchedKeys + = key + ","; 
    }
 }

 if(matchFound)
   lbl.Text = "The string has " + matchedKeys;

 else
   lblText = " NO Match Found !";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One more thing to ask.. How to make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

will be easier to achieve on Database side. For SQL Server it will be like

@lookup as your parameter

```
SELECT k.Word FROM Keywords k
WHERE @lookup like '%' + k.Work + '%'
```

This will return you a collection of keywords that were found in the string you passed as parameter to this query string (stored procedure)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```cs
      // list from DB
       var list = new List<string> { "ABC", "CDE", "EFG" };
        var selectedResult = new List<string>();
        var a = "and abc asd dsa efg";
        list.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var result = a.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(x.ToUpperInvariant());
                if (result)
                {
                    selectedResult.Add(x);
                }
            });


        var joined = selectedResult.Count > 0 ? string.Join(",", selectedResult) : "No Match";
```